# Why does my store.getState(); is undefined ? (react/redux)

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm learning how to use state with react/redux. From what I've read I kind of understand that state is accessible "everywhere" when using Redux. I've build an example [here](https://jsbin.com/citehi/edit?html,console,output). In this example when I'm looking at my react/redux dev tools, state and props seems to be perfectly well defined. From this example I can access the store with : `$r.store.getState().TheStateIwantFromMyStore;`.

However when I'm trying to display my state result inside my component with something like this `<p>{store.getState().TheStateIwantFromMyStore}<p>` I've got the following error `"store is not defined"`.

Why is that ? What should I do to display the result of my store ?

Thanks.

P.S : JS bin edited. It's working fine. thanks you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this for your component:

```
const DisplayTable = ({test, DisplayTable}) => {
    return (
    <div>
        <button onClick={DisplayTable}>cool</button>
        <p>{test}</p>
    </div> )
}
```

Comment: Hi John, I'm actually using the connect component in my example. It does seems to work fine looking at my react dev tools. Moreover I've already been following the Dan Abramov but still I can't understand and find a solution to my problem.

Comment: I see.. sorry I only read your question, after looking at the code I see you've got something that does look close to what you want. I see you are mapping two things to props though, and only accepting one thing. I'm not sure why 'test' is ending up as a function though when you should be mapping your state to it so it should just default to 0. Then you should be pulling out DisplayTable as well which is the action you've maped.

Comment: The main things I did were pulling out the props you wanted (test and DisplayTable) and using them. You were actually pretty close.

Comment: I was just about to post this same answer :). The key here is that stateless functional components take `props` as an argument, so you need to destructure it to access individual props directly. Oddly enough, the version Simon wrote actually works too, it's just confusingly written because it maps a prop called 'test' via mapStateToProps, but never actually uses that prop. It instead names the props argument 'test', and then correctly accesses the DisplayTable prop added by mapDispatchToProps. It's also confusing that the function is given the same name as the component itself.

Comment: Simon, the problem is that you still have `onClick={test.DisplayTable}` instead of `onClick={DisplayTable}`

Comment: hum ok. I think I start understanding the differences between mapStateToProps and mapDispachToProps. I can clearly see that I'm using one to dispatch my action and the other one to access my state. That's why I need to argument in my function. However I'm not clear what const is, if it a function or not and if test and DisplayTable are arguments. and also I don't really understand you when you say _you are mapping two things to props_... what do you mean ? thanks a lot anyway :)

Comment: React stateless functional components (which your DisplayTable component is) only accept a single argument - the props object, which contains all props passed down from its parent, plus any that you've injected via react-redux connect(). `mapStateToProps` injects new properties into the props object from your Redux state. `mapDispatchToProps` injects new properties into the props object that have access to your Redux store's dispatch method, thus allowing you to dispatch actions from within your component.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you haven't provided the Store as the prop in the provider tag.
This is an `index.jsx` or `index.js` file.

```
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App/>
    </Provider>
```

I was having the same problem and it got solved when the store was added.